# Distribution Function (Chap 6 Folland)

Tags: real-analysis

Folland, Prop 6.23 reads as follows:

> If $\lambda_f(\alpha) < \infty$ for all $\alpha > 0 $ and $\phi$ is a nonnegative Borel measurable function on $(0,\infty)$, then $$\int_X \phi \, \circ \, |f| \, d\mu = - \int_0^\infty \phi(\alpha) d\lambda_f(\alpha)$$
>   where $\lambda_f(\alpha) = \mu(\{x:|f(x) > \alpha\})$

The proof begins by noting that if $\nu$ is a negative Borel measure then we have: $\nu(E) = -\mu(|f|^{-1}(E))$ where $E$ is any Borel set. Then he proceeds to write:

> this means that $\int_X \phi \, \circ \, |f| \, d\mu = - \int_0^\infty \phi(\alpha) d\lambda_f(\alpha)$ when $\phi$ is the characteristic function of a Borel set.

I'm having trouble writing down the integrals from the observation that $\nu(E) = -\mu(|f|^{-1}(E))$.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\phi =I_E$ we have $\phi \circ |f|=I_{|f|^{-1}(E)}$. [To see this check that if one side has the value $1$ then  so does the other]. Hence $\int \phi \circ |f|d\mu=\mu (|f|^{-1}(E))$. On the other hand $-\int_0^{\infty} \phi d\lambda_f =-\lambda_f(E)=\mu (|f| >c)=\mu (|f|^{-1}(E))$ if $E=(c, \infty)$. This  proves the equality when the Borel set $E$ has the form $(c,\infty)$. The case  of a general Borel set can be handled using Monotone Class Theorem.